# How can I reference class instances that I have passed into a Map as keys JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, graph, vertex

I am implementing a graph class using a Map as an adjacency list, with a simple class Vertex that I am using to represent each node in the graph:

```
export class Vertex {
    constructor(value) {
        if (value) this.value = value;
        else throw new Error("Value must be specified");
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    setValue(value) {
        if (value) this.value = value;
        else throw new Error("Value must be specified");
    }
}
```

Then in my graph class I have implemented a constructor and 2 methods for adding vertices and edges:

```
export class UndirectedGraph {
    constructor() {
        this.adjacencyList = new Map();
    }

    addVertex(value) {
        if (value) {
            const vertex = new Vertex(value);
            this.adjacencyList.set(vertex, []);
        }
    }

    addEdge(to, from) {
        if (
            !to ||
            !from ||
            !(to.constructor === Vertex && from.constructor === Vertex)
        ) {
            throw new Error("Arguments must be of type Vertex");
        }
        if (
            !this.adjacencyList.get(to) ||
            !this.adjacencyList.get(from)
        ) {
            throw new Error(
                "Both arguments must already be nodes in this undirected graph"
            );
        }
        this.adjacencyList.get(to).push(from);
        this.adjacencyList.get(from).push(to);
    }

    getAdjacencyList() {
        return this.adjacencyList;
    }
}
```

Then I want to call the `addEdge()` function to create an edge between 2 instances of type Vertex:

```
const graph = new UndirectedGraph();
graph.addVertex("A");
graph.addVertex("B");
graph.addVertex("B");
graph.addEdge(..., ...);
```

What do I pass to the `addEdge()` function to create an edge between "A" and a particular instance of "B"? I have no variable for the Vertex instances that I can reference.

I want the graph to be able to store duplicate values, such as names, so using class instances seems like the obvious choice but now I am stuck on how to access the values they contain because I am unsure how to search for class instances within the Map i.e. `graph.getAdjacencyList().get(...)`. All help appreciated

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "I want the graph to be able to store duplicate values, such as names, so using class instances seems like the obvious choice".

Comment: My train of thought was that if I just add strings or numbers or whatever then any duplicates will just get muddled. E.g. how could I tell one "John Smith" string from another "John Smith" string? Class instances are unique so I should be able to distinguish which "John Smith" I am referring to

Comment: If you want to be able to store multiple vertexes with the same string value, but still distinguish between them easily, you'll need to store another piece of data on them like an ID. Use the string only for human-readable display, but do actual work with the IDs. Not sure how class instances would let you distinguish between vertexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `addVertex` method creates the `Vertex` instance and the `addEdge` method expects that very instance as a parameter, you need to make it available to the caller of these methods - by `return`ing it:

```
…
addVertex(value) {
    if (value) {
        const vertex = new Vertex(value);
        this.adjacencyList.set(vertex, []);
        return vertex;
    }
    // else throw new Error("no value given")?
}
…
```

Then you can use it like

```
const graph = new UndirectedGraph();
const vertex1 = graph.addVertex("A");
const vertex2 = graph.addVertex("B");
const vertex3 = graph.addVertex("B");
graph.addEdge(vertex1, vertex2);
graph.addEdge(vertex1, vertex3);
graph.addEdge(vertex2, vertex3);
```

Comment: This relies on the user storing the returned value, is there a way of ensuring that they do this rather than just calling graph.addVertex()

Comment: Yes of course they will do this, otherwise they could not add edges between them… The only alternative would be to give them unique ids (instead of, or in addition to, the values)