# How to look up class instance that is used as a key in a Map JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, dictionary

I want to be able to set a class instance as a key in a Map and then be able to look it up:

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.map = new Map();
    }

    addValue(value) {
        if (value) {
            const b = new B(value);
            this.map.set(b, "Some value");
        }
    }

    getMap() {
        return this.map;
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

So if I do this...

```
const a = new A();
a.addValue("B");
// Now I want to print the value of the class B instance to the console - what do I pass in?
console.log(a.getMap().get(...).getValue());
```

...what do I pass in to `.get(...)` to reference the instance of class B?

Comment: You really want to make the `addValue` method `return` the instance it creates, so that you can then use it to look up the value in the map.

Comment: This seems to be very much a duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59309381/1048572), just without the specific use case 
- which makes your requirements hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In such case you would have to pass the exact same object (so it is not enough to create another one with identical content, because you can not provide your own comparator for the class, and built-in `==`/`===` will say they are different):

```js
class mykey {
  constructor(something) {
    this.something=something;
  }
}

let map=new Map();

map.set(new mykey("hello"),"hellotest");
console.log("new key:",map.get(new mykey("hello")));

let key=new mykey("key");
map.set(key,"keytest");
console.log("reused key:",map.get(key));

let dupekey=new mykey("key");
console.log("==",key==dupekey);
console.log("===",key===dupekey);
```

Of course there are "things" what `==`/`===` compares better, for example strings. If you stringify your key objects (like into JSON), that suddenly works:

```js
class mykey {
  constructor(something) {
    this.something=something;
  }
}

let map=new Map();

console.log(JSON.stringify(new mykey("hello")));
map.set(JSON.stringify(new mykey("hello")),"hellotest");
console.log(map.get(JSON.stringify(new mykey("hello"))));
```

Comment: This JSON.stringify() approach seems like a good way to go. How would I be able to tell the difference between 2 Class B instances that have the same value?

Comment: @PumpkinBreath I thought the point was to treat them as same. If you need to differentiate, `===` will tell them inequal already.

Comment: Well ultimately I want to use this strategy to update a Map that represents an adjacency list for a graph structure. So each map entry will look like this: Map {value: someValue} => [...values]. I would need to know which someValue was related to which array of ...values. Would this work for that scenario?

Comment: @PumpkinBreath in that case, and assuming that `someValue` is not unique, you would need to store the "original" node objects, perhaps in an array. But that is just the coding part. I am not sure if a generic graph could be stored this way as any node can be a key in the `Map` only once.

Comment: Hmmm ok, perhaps this is not the best way to go to implement this graph. I thought that using class instances would allow many objects with the same value to be added and then retrieved to view their connections but it sounds like it's not a very practical solution due to this "original" node problem.

Comment: @PumpkinBreath is it a graph in mathematical sense, or is it something related to graphics (meshes, tesselations and the like)?

Comment: It's a graph as in the kind of data structure you would use to represent a friend network, like a Tree